# Select an object with different assignation in another column

Tags: postgresql, select

Simplified my problem with this table, I want to select in PostgreSQL only the people that have paid, I have another guys that have paid and have not paid I want to exclude those people, thank you

```
People Payment Debt/n
John   Pay     $100
John   Paid    $200
Luis   Paid    $150   
Luis   Paid    $300
```

Comment: What should be the result in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT People
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY People
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE Payment = 'Pay') = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another alternate , assuming your table name is "people_payments"

```
Select People from people_payments 
where Payment='Paid'
and People NOT IN (Select People from people_payments where Payment='Pay') ;
```